# How to completely remove margins and make div full width

Tags: html, css

hello i am workin on a page which i have used a 2 column and 1 row responsive grids using html and css

the grids works alright, but then i have noticed there is a margin on the left and right of this grids.

i am trying to eliminate this margins, but dsent work for me

```
<style>
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 50%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}

</style>


<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
    This is column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
    This is column 2
    </div>
</div>
```

with the madding and padding both set to zero, please how can i make sure this margins on the left and right of my grids are off.
this is a link to the page and a screenshot too

```
http://andymurphy.tv/index.php/landing/
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a rule setting margins to auto that is setting each margin to 2048px for what ever reason... `.tve_lp_hybrid-homepage2 .tve_content_width,.tve_lp_hybrid-homepage2 .thrv_page_section .out .in`

Comment: its a template, it ws set by default, hw do i over ride this

Comment: do you want it full screen?

Comment: Since you are using a wordpress template you are probably able to tell this part of your page to be full width. Adjusting the css could be very counterproductive, since the template uses a lot of interesting stuff like this: .tve_post_lp .tve_lp_content .out {width: 6080px; margin-left: -2500px;}

Comment: Your markup does not show the problem.

Comment: ok, bt wat abt the page link iv dropped it sure can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is giving that padding. To override it use this

```
<div class="pswr out" style="background-color: #EAEAEA">
    <div class="in darkSec pddbg">
        <div class="thrv_wrapper thrv_custom_html_shortcode">
            <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                    This is column 1
                </div>
                <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                    This is column 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want it full screen?

Comment: yes that red 1 row and two columns, they need to fit to that section

Comment: You template is not like that. Why not bake the background color of that row red too or any one that fits the column so it would look like the whole row while you still keep the template.

Comment: the red was just shw the variety between the 2 column row and the remaining part which had margins

Comment: Updated my code. the html has to be like that. there was an extra div with a class that won't make it full width.

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
body {

 margin : 0;

}
```

Comment: yea, but thats ur page nt this page

Comment: @Tee Famakin , You have not  class `span_2_of_2` , please check your code.you have 2 class with same name `span_1_of_2`

Answer (score 0):

That's a padding not a margin, so you need to set `padding: 0` on the element or parent/s.

**EDIT:**

```
.tve_lp_content tve_editor_main_content tve_empty_dropzone tve_content_width,
.tve_lp_template_wrapper:not(.tve_lp_blank).tve_post_lp .tve_lp_content .out,
.tve_post_lp .out .in,
.tve_post_lp .tve_lp_content { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: edited with more complete answer, you should be able to spot those changes without our help though

Comment: destroyed the page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, !important overrides any already set padding

```
body {

 padding : 0 !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start trying to use bootstrap? 
http://getbootstrap.com/

With bootstrap it is easy to make column lay-outs and by using `container-fluid` you are able to get the full-width of a page.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            Column one
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            Column two
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A second possible solution to your problem would be to add the following to your css:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks bro, am in this one already which dosent suport bootstrap, besides i use bootstrap

Comment: So it doesn't support bootstrap but you are using it? if it doesn't support it. Why would you try to use it?

Comment: am nt using bootsrap, i just used a grid of a column using css

Comment: Ah okay, I know it's not the best solution but try using negative margins/paddings Example: margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px;. If this doesn't work try using a width: 100%;

Comment: it wasnt responsive for diff screens we i did that

Comment: The simplest answer to your problem is add the following to your CSS: body { margin: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

As DeathStorm suggested you can try using negative margins, even though I agree it's not the best solution.

In your current codebase that would give

```
  .section.group {
    margin-left: -42px;
    margin-right: -42px;
    display: flex; /* Only needed for equal width columns */
  }

  .section.group > .col {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Only needed for equal width columns */
  }
```